# pyqt5 how to make a checkbox lock two Qsliders together

Tags: pyqt5

I have made a GUI using using Qt Designer running in python [here](https://github.com/Electrik-rich546456/Light_Gui)

How do I add code to my project to add a checkbox that locks (have their values changed together whatever they may be. 0 - 100 range) both my Qsliders together. See picture below.

Please feel free to ask if more info is needed.

[image: New design]

Comment: By "lock" do you mean disable both sliders, or have their values changed together?

Comment: Hi, Good point. I have edited the original post. I mean have their values changed together whatever they may be. 0-100 range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would connect each slider's `valueChanged` signal to the other's `setValue` slot when the checkbox is checked, and disconnect when unchecked.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(QSlider(Qt.Horizontal))
        vbox.addWidget(QCheckBox('Lock', toggled=self.toggleLocked))
        vbox.addWidget(QSlider(Qt.Horizontal))

    def toggleLocked(self, state):
        s1, s2 = self.findChildren(QSlider)
        if state:
            s2.setValue(s1.value())
            s1.valueChanged[int].connect(s2.setValue)
            s2.valueChanged[int].connect(s1.setValue)
        else:
            s1.valueChanged[int].disconnect()
            s2.valueChanged[int].disconnect()        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Template()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks one more question how do i make it a proportional lock like in an audio mixer? when locked they stay at the same values before lock. As in slider A set 50. slide B set 10. So Until slider A value gets to 100 and 10 then they would both be 10 and stay locked until told otherwise   ?

Comment: @Love-to-Make I don't understand your example. If you want them to move proportionally then it would be by the ratio of their values, in this case 5/1 or 1/5.

Comment: I am not to sure how else to describe it. your example works  ok .if slider_A is set at 75 and slide_B is set at 80 and i click the lock button i want it to stay at that ratio until they line up again by me  moving any of the sliders. eg click and drag slide_A to 100. slide_B will move up and get to 100 first and stay there till slide_A gets there and vice-verca

Comment: @Love-to-Make Ok and just to be clear, if slider_A is moved to 60 should slider_B move to 64 (A * 80 / 75) or to 65 (A + 5)?

Comment: No the sliders could very easily be sat at a completely different amount like slide A set 10 and slide B set at 50.

Comment: Or slide A  at100 and slide B at 25 
one lock is clicked  they stay like pavucontrol does wil left and right balance on the audio channels